# Will Mac OS X 10.5 ever update Java to 1.6 version?

Tags: mac-osx, java

Will Mac OS X 10.5 ever update its Java SDK to 1.6 version?

Comment: If you are concerned about current versions, why are you running 10.5?  The upgrade to 10.6 is trivially cheap.

Comment: The thing is that I work in a company that develops a product that must run in Win, Mac (10.5 and 10.6). So I can upgrade, but maybe our clients(universities) can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've installed the relevant updates (just run Software Update until you're up to date if you're not sure), then you do have Java 1.6.

The default Java install will still be 1.5, but you can get Java 1.6 by setting the `JAVA_VERSION` environment variable to `1.6` before running a Java application.

```
$ JAVA_VERSION=1.6 java -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04-248-9M3125)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.3-b01-101, mixed mode)
```

Alternatively you can also run the 1.6 version from `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Commands/java`

Note that Java 1.6 is only supported on 64-bit Intel Macs.

Comment: how to change default java http://li-ma.blogspot.com/2009/01/change-default-java-version-on-mac.html

Answer (score 3):

Assuming by "Mac OS 1.5" you mean "Mac OS X 10.5" the answer appears to be yes, two years ago:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1856

But the actual System 1.5 would be from the late 80s, so I assume no. :-)

Comment: Yes, I meant Mac OS X 1.5.

Weird thing is that if I run java -version in my Mac I get that it is 1.5. May I have not applied the right updates??

Comment: The X in "OS X" is the roman numeral for 10. There is no such thing as Mac OS X v1.5.  Either it's version 10 point something, or it's not OS X.

Comment: X is a 10, but the version number is also 10.something. Of course, uname gives another version number which I think in 10.6 happens to be 10.0 (it was 9.0 for 10.5).

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can get it as a [SoyLatte](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/) .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I meant officially released by apple.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, Java 1.6 was usable only on 64bit Intel machines, leaving out the first generation Intel systems and everything PPC.